# No data when back testing pine script code

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am very new to using pinescript.  I tried just writing a simple crossover trading strategy using moving averages.  I copied the code from a tutorial video on youtube.  The issue is that in the video pine 4 was used, and I am using the newest version, pine 5, which I'm sure is the cause of the issue.

The issue is that when I add my strategy to the chart, it shows no data for overview and list of trades, meaning my script must not be executing the trades.

Like I said I am new to pinescript, as this is my first strategy I created.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bitcoin SMA", overlay = true, initial_capital = 1000, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, margin_long = 100, margin_short = 100)


start_date = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Start Date")
start_month = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Start Month")
start_year = input.int(defval = 2020, title = "Start Year")

end_date = input.int(defval = 1, title = "End Date")
end_month = input.int(defval = 1, title = "End Month")
end_year = input.int(defval = 2021, title = "End Year")

fast_ma_period = input.int(defval = 5, title = "Fast MA")
slow_ma_period = input.int(defval = 15, title = "Slow MA")


fast_ma = ta.sma(close,fast_ma_period)
slow_ma = ta.sma(close, slow_ma_period)

between_dates = (time >= timestamp(start_year, start_month, start_date, 1, 0) and (time < timestamp(end_year, end_month, end_date, 23, 59)))

plot(fast_ma, color = color.green, linewidth = 1)
plot(slow_ma, color = color.yellow, linewidth = 3)

buy_condition = ta.crossover(fast_ma, slow_ma)
sell_condition = ta.crossunder(fast_ma, slow_ma)


if between_dates
    strategy.entry("BTC enter", strategy.long, 1, when = buy_condition)
    strategy.close("BTC close", when = sell_condition)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two mistakes.

1. With `strategy.entry("BTC enter", strategy.long, 1, when = buy_condition)`, you are telling that you want to buy **1** BTC. But you don't have enough capital. Your initial capital is set to $1000. Increase it to something like $10000.
2. First argument of `strategy.close()` is the id of the trade you want to close. In this case you should pass `"BTC enter"`, instead of `"BTC close"`.

Here is the full code for you:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bitcoin SMA", overlay = true, initial_capital = 10000, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, margin_long = 100, margin_short = 100)


start_date = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Start Date")
start_month = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Start Month")
start_year = input.int(defval = 2020, title = "Start Year")

end_date = input.int(defval = 1, title = "End Date")
end_month = input.int(defval = 1, title = "End Month")
end_year = input.int(defval = 2021, title = "End Year")

fast_ma_period = input.int(defval = 5, title = "Fast MA")
slow_ma_period = input.int(defval = 15, title = "Slow MA")


fast_ma = ta.sma(close,fast_ma_period)
slow_ma = ta.sma(close, slow_ma_period)

between_dates = (time >= timestamp(start_year, start_month, start_date, 1, 0) and (time < timestamp(end_year, end_month, end_date, 23, 59)))

plot(fast_ma, color = color.green, linewidth = 1)
plot(slow_ma, color = color.yellow, linewidth = 3)

buy_condition = ta.crossover(fast_ma, slow_ma)
sell_condition = ta.crossunder(fast_ma, slow_ma)


if between_dates
    strategy.entry("BTC enter", strategy.long, 1, when = buy_condition)
    strategy.close("BTC enter", when = sell_condition)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi vitruvius, thank you very much for the response!  Is there a way to trade a dollar amount of a stock as opposed to amount of shares, such as buying/selling $1000 USD vs buying/selling 1 share?  I tried finding something about that in the pine 5 documentation, but didn't have any luck.